# Testflight with expiring certificate

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, testflight

I have a distribution certificate which is about to expire. I have the following questions regarding that:

1. What will happen with the users that have the app installed?
2. I also have some Builds in pipeline within Testflight which were also signed with that certificate. Is it correct that i cannot activate those after the certificate expired?
3. Can i just issue a new certificate and build/sign/upload another Testflight build? Will the update from the app signed with the old certificate to the app signed with the new certifcate work without any problems?

Thank you in advance for help!

Answer (score 5):

First, TestFlight builds only work for 30 days, I believe.

1. Users with apps installed that were signed with the expired certificate will no longer be able to run the app (the app will launch and then quickly exit, appearing to crash).   I haven't confirmed this because I never let it happen (always using the new cert at least 30 days before the old one expired)
2. **Edit** Originally, I didn't believe TestFlight builds would run after revoking your certificate, it appears I was wrong. TestFlight builds are re-signed by Apple prior to distribution, which means revoking or having a certificat expire won't affect apps that have been distributed via TestFVlight.  It simply means that you will not be able to submit an app to TestFlight for deployment if your cert is revoked or expired.
3. Yes, generate a new cert, build the apps again with the new certificate and provisioning profile and push them out through TestFlight.  The new app should install just fine and replace the old app.

Comment: I just revoked the certificate. The Testflight Apps are still working. Does it take some time to refresh?

Comment: Interesting.  I've never gotten to that point, but if you had done it with a regular developer or ad hoc distribution cert, the apps would have stopped working immediately if the device had a network connection.

Comment: Can confirm that we were able to install and run older TestFlight builds, after the current certificate was revoked.

Comment: Testflight must resign the builds with an Apple cert, just like ofiicial App Store apps.  I haven't used Testflight, but that is the only way you would be able to still run your apps after revoking your certificate.  I'll update my answer to reflect that.